# How to detect if any app goes fullscreen or exiting fullscreen?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to disable notifications at my app when there is another app fullscreen like powerpoint or VLC to do not bother a user.

For now, I get to this code, but it always returns true. Whether there is some app fullscreen or not. I am not sure whether this should work only for app bars or also taskbar.

```
HWND  hWnd;
hWnd = FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd", nullptr);
if( hWnd )
{
    APPBARDATA apd;
    apd.cbSize = sizeof(APPBARDATA);
    apd.hWnd = hWnd;
    bool uState = bool(SHAppBarMessage(ABN_FULLSCREENAPP , &apd));
    if(uState)
        qDebug()<<"fullscreen";
    else
        qDebug()<<"not fullscreen";
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid message, ABN_xxx messages are sent from the OS to the appbar owner as a notification.  You didn't create the appbar, so that won't fly.  Find good solutions at SO by googling "winapi detect fullscreen app".

Comment: I think [SHQueryUserNotificationState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shqueryusernotificationstate) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @RaymondChen I think your comment should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ABN_FULLSCREENAPP` is not a message you send to the shell, it's a message the shell sends to you when an application enters or leaves full screen mode.  The message is sent to the owner of an app bar created with [`ABM_NEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/shell/abm-new).

Documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787965.aspx).

My reading of the documentation is that you have to create an app bar to receive this message but you may be able to set it to zero height or width with [`ABM_SETPOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/shell/abm-setpos) if you want to hide it.